# Make: Skip hard steps

Tags: gnu-make

I have a Makefile of the following form:

```
intermediate.file: base.file
    # make stuff

target.file: intermediate.file
    # make stuff
```

Now, I only want `make` to (re-)build target.file if it doesn't exist (or maybe if I pass -B), because these steps may take ages.

How do I `make this happen`?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  As it stands your makefile will rebuild target.file if it doesn't exist or is older than intermediate.file.  What do you want to skip?

Comment: I never want to make `intermediate.file` if `target.file` exists. If possible, I only want to rebuild `target.file` if nonexistent, because both processes are time-consuming (and the `base.file` is not subject to frequent changes).

Comment: I could stop the `make target.file` at a higher level, but that just doesn't feel like the standard way. Correct me if I'm wrong though!

Comment: So you only need intermediate.file if you're building target.file?

Comment: Generally, yes. I might occasionally need `intermediate.file` for verification purposes. So I hoped there was a special make target (like .PHONY) which does what I need. (I found a list of special targets, but I deemed their specs really hard to understand.)

Comment: You could only have target.file depend on base.file, and don't have intermediate.file as a rule at all.  I'll put this in the answer so I can format it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162665/discussion-between-jim-baldwin-and-ldericher).

Answer (score 0):

This would only build intermediate.file if target.file needs to get built.  Still not quite sure if this is what you're looking for...

```
target.file: base.file
    # build intermediate.file
    # build target.file
```

Answer (score 0):

In the given form

```
intermediate.file: base.file
    # make stuff

target.file: intermediate.file
    # make stuff
```

`make` will build your `target.file` anyway only if you specify it explicitly on the command line (`make target.file`) because it is not the first rule that `make` encounters. If you have another target which is higher up the dependency tree (depends on `target.file`) and comes first in your file, you could make `target.file` an order-only prerequisite. In this case I would warn however with a shell command that you are building from an old version:

```
final_target: | target.file
    if [ "intermediate.file" -nt "target.file" ]; then echo "Warning: building from an outdated version of target.file!!!"; fi
    touch final_target

intermediate.file: base.file
    # make stuff

target.file: intermediate.file
    # make stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.SECONDARY` special target.

It tells make that a file is intermediate, and allows to rebuild it only if it is needed (aka, if its own prerequisites are newer than the target specifying it as a prerequisite).

Your makefile will look like :

```
intermediate.file: base.file
    # make stuff

target.file: intermediate.file
    # make stuff
.SECONDARY: intermediate.file
```

Relevant documentation of GNU Make:

[Special Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html)
 (`.INTERMEDIATE` and `.SECONDARY`)

[Chained Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules)